# Stripe payments started throwing this error out of nowhere. Any ideas? php laravel framework using stripe API

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

ApiConnection in CurlClient.php line 234:
Could not connect to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts). Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem persists, you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com.

(Network error [errno 6]: Could not resolve host: api.stripe.com)

Comment: FYI, I am able to CURL call the API from the server command line without any errors.  Which makes me think the problem is NOT a stripe problem.

Comment: switched back from live keys to sandbox and no change...  also disabled UFW and no change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Ubuntu, you may want to try rebooting the server.  If that doesn't work, you'll probably want to write into [Support](https://support.stripe.com/email) about this.